# Python3 Replacing special character from .csv file after convert the same from JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to develop a program using Python3.6.4 which convert a JSON file into a CSV file and also we need to clean the data in the csv file. as for example:

My JSON File:

```
{emp:[{"Name":"Bo#b","email":"bob@gmail.com","Des":"Unknown"},
{"Name":"Martin","email":"mar#tin@gmail.com","Des":"D#eveloper"}]}
```

**Problem 1:**

After converting that into csv its creating a blank row between every 2 rows. As

```
**Name     email               Des**
[<BLANK ROW>]
Bo#b     bob@gmail.com       Unknown
[<BLANK ROW>]
Martin   mar#tin@gmail.com   D#eveloper
```

**Problem 2:**

In my code I am using `emp` but I need to use it dynamically.

```
fobj = open("D:/Users/shamiks/PycharmProjects/jsonSamle.txt")
jsonCont = fobj.read()
print(jsonCont)
fobj.close()
employee_parsed = json.loads(jsonCont)
emp_data = employee_parsed['employee']
```

As we will not know the structure or content of up-coming JSON file.

**Problem 3:**

I also need to remove all `#` characters from the CSV file.

Comment: Please provide more information about your current approach. What is the code used for csv conversion?

Comment: Yes, please provide your complete current code to allow us to help with problem 1.

Answer (score 0):

For solving Problem 3, you can use `.replace` (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm).
For problem 2, you can use the dictionary keys and then get the zeroth item out of it.

```
fobj = open("D:/Users/shamiks/PycharmProjects/jsonSamle.txt")
jsonCont = fobj.read().replace("#", "")
print(jsonCont)
fobj.close()
employee_parsed = json.loads(jsonCont)
first_key = employee_parsed.keys()[0]
emp_data = employee_parsed[first_key]
```

I can't solve problem 1 without more code to see how your are exporting the result.  It may be that your data has newlines in it.  In which case, you could add `.replace("\n","")` and/or `.replace("\r","")` after the previous replace so the line would read `fobj.read().replace("#", "").replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "")`.